# Read stored pickle file using a class

Tags: python, pickle

How can I read this pickle file in using a `class`.  For some reason the this gives a `TypeError` stating I have multiple items for the primary argument `p_file`.

```
import pickle
import datetime

some_file={'date': datetime.date(2020,2,22),
           'fruit': 'apples'
          }

with open(r'parameter.p','wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(some_file, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

class load_pickle():
    def ReadPickle(p_file=None):
        infile=open(p_file,'rb')
        read_pickle=pickle.load(infile)
        infile.close()
        print(read_pickle)

test=load_pickle()
test.ReadPickle(p_file=r'parameter.p')
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: You missed out the `self` parameter in your method definition. Because you (for some reason) put the method in a class and called it via an instance, the instance is passed along as the first argument to the method.

Comment: Got it, i added `def ReadPickle(self,p_file=None)` which worked for that, however, now i am recieving a different error.  `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)`.  Do you know how to handle this?

Comment: Sounds like you have another question which you should post a [mre] for.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback @khelwood, I am somewhat new to using python.  I will review your feedback and try to pose my questions better in future posts.  I appolgize for the confusion.